# Small screen floating content/extra width

Tags: javascript, android, html, css, responsive-design

I'm having this problem on my responsive site,
Whenever the screen is xsmall I get this extra-space to the right, like another 
screen to the side with no content, I have a fixed background, but I checked its width and its always the size if the device,
so when the user swipes left the content 'slides' left and you see just the background.

[link to image of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bWdXh.jpg)

Comment: any code you wanna share?

Comment: Can you provide code or a jsfiddle of what you have done ?

Comment: Found the problem,
It was sass throwing errors in the background and I couldn't detect it,
I had an unclosed 'backgrounnd-color' statement.

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem, It was sass throwing errors in the background and I couldn't detect it, I had an unclosed 'backgrounnd-color' statement in style-small.